IOS Swift WKUIDelegate methods not called (Xcode 16)
I encountered a problem where my app, which worked perfectly in July, no longer works when I try to build it now.
Certain methods, such as the one below, are no longer being called in Xcode 16.1.
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, runJavaScriptAlertPanelWithMessage message: String, initiatedByFrame frame: WKFrameInfo, completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: message, preferredStyle: UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad ? .alert : .actionSheet)
        alertController.addAction(
          UIAlertAction(title: "Ok".localized, style: .default, handler: { (action) in completionHandler() })
        )

        if let controller = topMostViewController() {
            controller.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
        
    }


I couldn’t find any information about this from Apple, but I tried using the async version of these methods, and it worked.
So, it seems you must use the async versions of these types of methods:
func webView(
    _ webView: WKWebView,
    runJavaScriptAlertPanelWithMessage message: String,
    initiatedByFrame frame: WKFrameInfo
) async {
    let alertController = UIAlertController(
        title: nil,
        message: message,
        preferredStyle: UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad ? .alert : .actionSheet
    )
    
    alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok".localized, style: .default, handler: nil))
    
    if let controller = topMostViewController() {
        await MainActor.run {
            controller.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
}

